# What do the letters Japanese trainers use on the GTS to indicate IVs mean?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

When searching for trades on the GTS, I see a lot in the notes from Japanese (and Korean players, too) players indicating Pokemon IVs by different letters: A, B, C, D, H, S, like:

> HCDS4v

I usually don't know what I get until I do the trade, but sometimes I'm looking for something specific, like a Ditto with certain stat values and like to know what I would be getting beforehand.

Which stats correspond to which letters? How do I know if they are offering or wanting something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Japanese trainers indicate IVs using the letter "V" and indicate each stat in the order they appear on the Summary of each Pokemon:

- H = HP
- A = Attack
- B = Defence
- C = Sp. Atk
- D = Sp. Def
- S = Speed

If you have a 3 perfect IV Pokemon with perfect HP, Def, and Sp. Def, you would input something like:

> 3V HBD

If you are looking for Pokemon with Hidden Abilities be on the look out for these characters: ゆめ or ユメ (yume, lit. dream).

You can find the different natures in Japanese [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature#Nature_table).

Typically, if the notes end in ほしい　（hoshii, lit. wanted）or ください （kudasai, lit. please), this indicates that text the came before it is something that trainer wants.

If you see です（desu, lit. it is） at the end, it usually means to affirm preceding text.

E.g., "3VADSです, 3VHBCほしい" could indicate that the Japanese trainer is offering:

- a 3 perfect Attack, Sp. Def, and Speed IV (A, D, S) Pokemon

and wants:

- a 3 perfect HP, Def, and Sp. Atk IV (H, B, C) Pokemon

Comment: I was literally just about to ask the same question (although I wouldn't have been able to answer it :P) Nice work

Comment: Hah, Japanese-for-Pokemon-Traders-101 on Arqade. Nice job. :D

Comment: One I see quite often from Japanese players is '**tieba**', all lowercase. Do you know if this means anything in particular? I couldn't find anything online

Comment: @Robotnik Baidu Tieba is a chinese communication platform. So it's possibly a means of enticing online bartering for Pokémon. Don't quote me on that, I can't do much more without more context.